# Finding the largest random value in a set range, python

Tags: python

I have a range from 2 to 14 and it generates two random values from this range. How would I print out the biggest value first from those two numbers?

I currently have a lot of if statements but I wanted to know if there was a better way to do it.

```
Player_Card_1 = random.randint(2, 14)
Player_Card_2 = random.randint(2, 14)
Computer_Card_1 = random.randint(2, 14)
Computer_Card_2 = random.randint(2, 14)

def drawcards():
    if (Player_Card_2 > Player_Card_1) and (Computer_Card_2 > Computer_Card_1):
        print("Player_Card_2 [%d] Player_Card_1 [%d] " % (Player_Card_2, Player_Card_1))
        print("Computer_Card_2 [%d] Computer_Card_1 [%d] " % (Computer_Card_2, Computer_Card_1))
    elif (Computer_Card_2 > Computer_Card_1):
        print("Player_Card_1 [%d] Player_Card_2 [%d] " % (Player_Card_1, Player_Card_2))
        print("Computer_Card_2 [%d] Computer_Card_1 [%d] " % (Computer_Card_2, Computer_Card_1))
    elif (Player_Card_2 > Player_Card_1):
        print("Player_Card_2 [%d] Player_Card_1 [%d] " % (Player_Card_2, Player_Card_1))
        print("Computer_Card_1 [%d] Computer_Card_2 [%d] " % (Computer_Card_1, Computer_Card_2))
    else:
        print("Player_Card_1 [%d] Player_Card_2 [%d] " % (Player_Card_1, Player_Card_2))
        print("Computer_Card_1 [%d] Computer_Card_2 [%d] " % (Computer_Card_1, Computer_Card_2))
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max

Comment: A first approach to simplify can be to first care about the first line of output (player card) and then independently about the second line.